# converting string to jsx in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to store some text shown by a react native component in a realm database as a string. The problem is that some words in the text require different styling and so need to be wrapped in another text tag. For example:

```
        <Text>
        <Text> some text </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>bold word</Text>
        <Text> more text </Text>
        </Text>
```

How do I preserve the styling of individual words when they are stored, whether that be in realm or any other database? I.e. is there a way to render a string as jsx in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible because JSX is not parsed at runtime.

However, you can store the text in html format and render it in a [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html).
You can style the WebView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render multi-color strings, I used this utility. You can try to write something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {ReactNode} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

// In order to use this function, you need to pass strings of the type:
// 'Hello ||#FF5843|world||'
export function colorText(str: string): ReactNode {
  return (
    <>
      {str.split('||').map((item) => {
        if (item.indexOf('|') !== -1) {
          const coloredText = item.split('|');
          return <Text style={{color: coloredText[0]}}>{coloredText[1]}</Text>;
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```